# ¿Como agrupar resultados por Rango de Fecha en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Estoy haciendo un reporte donde debo sumar las ventas de las empresas dentro de un rango de fechas y agruparlas según su clasificación (linea blanca, muebles,otros,etc.), para agilizar el proceso quiero hacer un **view** pero no se como adaptarla para poder hacer un filtro sobre ella.

Esta es la sentencia que estoy usando:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESUMEN_VENTAS_ACUMULADAS AS SELECT ITE.CLA_ITE,DES_CLA,ITE.CTA_CON,DES_CTA,SUM(PRE_VTA) AS PRE_VTA,FEC_MOV FROM INVMOV AS MOV, INVITE AS ITE,INVCLA AS CLA WHERE MOV.COD_ITE = ITE.COD_ITE AND ITE.CLA_ITE = CLA.CLA_ITE GROUP BY CTA_CON;
```

Y asi la ocupo:

```
SELECT * FROM RESUMEN_VENTAS_ACUMULADAS WHERE FEC_MOV BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31';
```

Como estoy agrupando por la clasificación del ítem las fechas que me trae el **view** no me sirven para hacer el filtro. 
¿Como podría dar solución a este problema?

Answer (score 0):

No se puede si vas a usar una vista.

Justamente, todo el punto de usar una vista es que tengas la mayor parte del query resuelto. Como te query es una agrupacion, y la misma no es igual para todas las fechas, entonces no podes agrupar primero y filtrar por fechas despues.

En este caso, no te queda otra que Agrupar por la menor entidad posible (si fuera posible, por dias) y despues agrupar por los tipos que queres (esto, de ser posible). Y si no, directamente olvidarte de la vista y hacer un query que filtre y agrupe por los datos que necesitas.

Comment: Si, de hecho eso pretendo hacer ahora, pero quería preguntar si se podría hacer algo como lo que pensaba.